# Match and Countif

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have three columns. column 1 is a dashboard showing the results from data on column 2 and 3.

On column 2 there are boats in column D classified as "speed boats" or "slow boats".  Also on Column 2 there are motor serial numbers in column E for both speed and slow boats.(example- row 2 column D "speed" column E "555334")

On Column 3 there are a list of engine serial numbers in column G that match some of column 2 column E motor serial numbers.

How do I determine which motor serial numbers match the speed boats and which ones match the slow boats?  Should I use an additional COUNTIF and if so how?

I have figured out how to match the serial numbers but having difficulty determining the count of speed boats or slow boats that have matches.

{=COUNT(MATCH(E2:E11,G2:G11,0))}
Using Office 365

Basically in the image I am having difficulty determining the answers for B3 and B4.

[Hopefully this image akes sense on what I am trying to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJlw4.png)

Comment: I think you're failing to explain what is going on here. Try adding the screenshots of sheets 2 and 3 and explain more accurately where and what needs to be done. While you're at it, also share which version of Excel you're using.

Comment: Thank you.  I have added an image and consolidated it to one sheet. I also edited my post to only reference a single sheet.  Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Count Matches

- Since you're using Microsoft 365 now, you don't have to use braces for array formulas anymore.
- One of the problems you're facing is that `COUNTIF(S)` only works with ranges, not with arrays, e.g. `D2:D21="Speed"` is an array.
- If you put your data in Excel tables, you will basically never have to adjust the ranges in the formulas.

**Basic**

```
=COUNT(XMATCH(E2:E21,G2:G14))
=SUM(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(E2:E21,G2:G14))*(D2:D21="Speed"))
=SUM(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(E2:E21,G2:G14))*(D2:D21="Slow"))
```

**Advanced**

- This is a single formula that will spill into all 3 cells. It is assumed that the first row has the total boats while each of the next to rows has to start with either `Speed`, `Slow`, or any other *Type*, followed by a space (`LEFT/FIND`). It is a bit of a clumsy idea but it should make you wonder about the multitude of possibilities.

```
=LET(e,A2:A4,t,D2:D21,s,E2:E21,w,G2:G14,
    sw,XMATCH(s,w),
    el,LEFT(e,FIND(" ",e)-1),
MAKEARRAY(ROWS(el),1,LAMBDA(r,c,
    IF(r=1,COUNT(sw),
        SUM(ISNUMBER(sw)*(t=INDEX(el,r)))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  Works great and I found that I had a hidden character while trying to match as well so that was making my results incorrect.

Comment: How would I get the above basic match to work if Speed or Slow were further defined as Speed-50-A, Speed-50-B etc, and Slow-20-D, SLow-20-E etc.?  I have tried using "*50*" to capture the Speed matches but it is not calculating correctly.

Comment: I think that's too complicated to cover in the comments. Best ask another question. Post a link to it in your comments, so the interested (in this question) contributors could find it easily.

Comment: Thank you for the good advice. Here is a link to the new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75939196/sum-xmatch-multiple-columns