# SUM XMATCH Multiple Columns

Tags: excel, sum

[image: The formula is in the image that I am trying to get to work.]

I have attempted to use  the formula in the image but not getting the results desired.

Using Office 365--I'm trying to sum a column by using a common element in a text of the name.  It may be that when I add a number to the name my formula needs to be different than what I have.

Comment: I would split this out to evaluate each part and if all correct then combine step by step.

Comment: A handy trick can be using the 'Evaluate Formula' option within the 'Formulas' tab, whilst highlighting the cell containing a formula. Using this shows the final argument (containing " * 50 * ") returns all FALSE values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ISNUMBER` will give you `TRUE`/`FALSE` array and `SUM` will be `0`. Before summing you need to convert it to `1`/`0` array with `N` or `--`

Use `FIND` or `SEARCH` to get if text contains *-50-* not wildcards.

```
=SUM(N(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(Table2[Engine SN that Need Work],Table16[Boat Engine SN])*(FIND("-50-",Table16[Boat Type])>0))))
```

Result:

[image]